# Alexa Account Linking with firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, alexa-skills-kit

I want to authenticate firebase user on alexa skill kit. using unique UUID (which obtain when call sign In with email and password to firebase) Update that user data.

Help me.

Thank you.